# Выборка на SQL

Tags: sql

Доброй ночи всем! Сижу программирую целый день. Сейчас ночью уже плохо соображаю). Задача значит стоит такая: a.    получить список браков, в которых родилось 2-а ребенка.

В таблице peoples хранятся данные о родителях. В таблице marriages хранятся данные по заключенным и расторгнутым бракам. И в последней таблице, которая касается этой задачи хранятся дети - childrens. Структура такова:

[image]

Нарисовал в аксеце это, потому продублировалась таблица Peoples для матери и отца.
Запрос пишу такой, согласно задаче (Вывод браков и фамилий родителей, у которых родились 2-е детей в период брака):

```
SELECT m.ID_marriage, m.Date_begin_marriage, m.Date_end_marriage, a.Fam_people, a.Name_people, a.SecondName_people, b.Fam_people, b.Name_people, b.SecondName_people
FROM Marriages AS m, Peoples AS a, Peoples AS b
WHERE ((b.ID_people = m.Code_wife) AND (a.ID_people = m.Code_husband)
AND 2 = (Select COUNT(*) FROM Childrens c WHERE ((c.Code_father = a.ID_people ) AND (c.Code_mother =  b.ID_people) AND (c.Date_born > m.Date_begin_marriage) AND (c.Date_born < m.Date_begin_marriage))));
```

Запрос не выводит ничего. Хотя должен был вывести одну семью, у которой родились в браке 2-е. Я подзабыл уже писать вложенные SQL-запросы, потому могу ошибаться. Кто знает, как правильно? Буду благодарен.

Comment: Проверьте здесь AND (c.Date_born > m.Date_begin_marriage) AND **(c.Date_born < m.Date_begin_marriage)**

Comment: В конце вероятно должно быть and (c.Date_born < m.Date_end_marriage).
Т. е. последнее условие - дата рождения меньше даты расторжения брака, а не заключения как в Вашем запросе.

Comment: Да, спасибо всем. Действительно запрос должен был выглядеть так:

    SELECT m.ID_marriage, m.Date_begin_marriage, m.Date_end_marriage, a.Fam_people, a.Name_people, a.SecondName_people, b.Fam_people, b.Name_people, b.SecondName_people
    FROM Marriages AS m, Peoples AS a, Peoples AS b
    WHERE ((b.ID_people = m.Code_wife) AND (a.ID_people = m.Code_husband)
    AND 2 = (Select COUNT(*) FROM Childrens c WHERE ((c.Code_father = a.ID_people ) AND (c.Code_mother =  b.ID_people) AND (c.Date_born > m.Date_begin_marriage) AND (c.Date_born < m.Date_end_marriage))));

Comment: 1. Зачем Вам две одинаковых таблицы Peoples?

2. Детей следует связывать не с Peoples, а с Марьяж, если, конечно, внебрачных детей не бывает.

Comment: @BuilderC, это не одинаковые таблицы, а одна и та же. В аксеце когда строишь связи, если вторая таблица связывается с первой по двум полям, то дублируется изображение, для наглядности не более того. В данном случае Childrens зависит полями Code_father и Code_mother от таблицы Peoples по полю ID_People. Внебрачные дети есть там.